# Regex.Replace - pattern for correcting date format

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to format date entered by user. 
Dates are provided in the following format:

- d/M/yyyy (ie: 1/1/2012, but could be also 12/1/2012 or 1/12/2012)

however I need them converted to:

- dd/MM/yyyy (ie: 01/01/2012)

I managed to do it in non-Regex way, like this:

```
    string date = "1/1/2012";

    if (date.IndexOf("/") == 1)
    {
        date = "0" + date;
    }
    if (date.Substring(4, 1) == "/")
    {
        date = date.Insert(3, "0");
    }
```

I would really like to know how to do it with Regex.Replace, however, as it would probably be neater.

I tired different variations of the below:

```
    string date = "1/1/2012"

    date = Regex.Replace(date, @"\d{1}/", "0$&");
```

The above will work, but if the date is 12/1/2012, it will also make 102 out of 12. If I add ^ at the beginning of pattern I don't get the second number changed. I also tried combinations with [^|/] at the beginning, but also no luck. So at the moment it is either or.

Comment: I would use try parse with different formats - have you considered this?

Comment: I haven't - will look into it. However this question is purely to find out how to do it with Regex.Replace(), thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use word boundary `\b` which matches between a word character and a non-word character.

```
date = Regex.Replace(date, @"\b\d/", "0$&");
```

OR

```
date = Regex.Replace(date, @"\b(\d)/", "0$1/");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gN8fU7/2)

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure of the incoming format, I'd use `DateTime.ParseExact` instead, then use `.ToString()` to reformat the date:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

string reformatted = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but I actually wanted to know how to do it with Regex.Replace() - although I will definitely look into your advise as well :)